# Line up/down key mapping not working in Eclipse with Vrapper XML intellisense

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclipse-plugin, autohotkey, content-assist

I am using Eclipse Mars with Vrapper. I have mapped Line Up to ctrl+p and Line Down to to ctrl+n to select intellisense list item without using up and down arrows. This allows me use to intellisense without leaving main keyboard.

This works great for Java source but it is not working for xml file. ctrl+p and ctrl+n just doesn't focus on content assist window. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Vrapper contributor here.  
Are you sure `Ctrl+P` and `Ctrl+n` are not bound to any other commands? You can find these by litterally entering "Ctrl+P" in the "Find command" textbox of the "Keys" preferences page.

Comment: @JBert, Thanks for writing Vrapper, I can't live without it. Yes, I have checked my shortcuts Eclipse and they look correct. The problems is not with Vrapper but with eclipse xml file intellisense. Java source file work without issue. I have mapped ctrl+p and ctrl+n using autohotkey to up and down arrow. So, I am all set. Thanks for getting back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find solution for this but found a work around using Autohotkey. Please find the script below

```
    ;Eclipse Vrapper with intellisense
    #If WinActive("ahk_class SWT_Window0") or WinActive("ahk_class #32770")
    ^n::
        Send,{Down}
    return
    ^p::
        Send, {Up}
    return
    #If
```